# Fixed height of quill editor that fills a grid cell span

Tags: html, css, quill, ngx-quill

How can I force the quill editor to not exceed its initial height?

I have a grid layout with some items, all are basically external components, the heights of which I do not know (in the sense: I do not want to hard-code any heights, because I might change the contents or the content's own implementation changes).

In the example below, I have a 2x2 grid

```
Content1 Editor
Content2 Editor
```

where the editor spans two rows in the second column. (Here, `Editor` is actually a wrapper component around the actual editor tag occupying quill.)

My goal is now that the total grid/row height is determined by the other content, and the Editor uses the same height as the content.
The editor should *fill* its cells, but not exceed it once more text is entered in the editor. Instead, the editor content should scroll (and the toolbar stay in place).

First the snippet:

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [[{ header: [1, 2, false] }], ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']]
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 16px;
  grid: "O1 E" auto
        "O2 E" auto
      / auto auto;
  border: 1px solid; border-color: green;
}

#other1 {
  grid-area: O1;

  /* internal to the content: */
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#other2 {
  grid-area: O2;

  /* internal to the content: */
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#editor-cell {
  grid-area: E;
  align-self: stretch;
}

#editor-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

#editor-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.js"></script>
<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="other1">Other</div>
  <div id="other2">Content</div>
  <div id="editor-cell">
    <div id="editor-wrapper">
      <div id="editor-container">
        <div id="editor"><p>Sample</p><p>Line 2</p><p>Line 3</p><p>Line 4</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try it out and add an additional line in the editor (e.g. after "Line 4").
Notice how the other cells in the first column grow and there is now an unwanted additional gap between the content in the first column.

Due to the different components I use, I have a few levels of `div`s.
First is the `#editor-container`, which contains the actual quill editor and the toolbar that gets inserted above `#editor` inside `#editor-container`.
Then there is the `#editor-wrapper`, which wraps the whole container. Finally, we have the actual grid cell `#editor-cell`.

As you can see, I am using flex-layout. This at least makes quill use all available height - but it does not constrain its max-height.

The actual configuration of quill can also by dynamic, i.e. in some cases the toolbar might be two rows tall if there are many buttons on it.

*Additional info*: My actual application is an Angular app using `ngx-quill`. I want to adhere to view encapsulation and avoid any global styles or ::ng-deep, i.e. no changes to the internal styles/themes provided by quill.

Oh, and of course a CSS-only solution would be very much appreciated. :D

But *any* kind of work-around would also be very welcome.

### Solution attempt #1

I now have a first hacky work-around by fixing the grid row's height and setting `min-height: 0` on the `#editor`.
I consider `#editor` to be an implementation detail, so I would rather not have any CSS applied to it, but I can live with that.

But I definitely do not want to fix the grid row's height (`"O1 E" 70px`).
I am still struggling to find a solution for that.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [[{ header: [1, 2, false] }], ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']]
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 16px;
  grid: "O1 E" 70px
        "O2 E" 70px
      / auto auto;
  border: 1px solid; border-color: green;
}

#other1 {
  grid-area: O1;

  /* internal to the content: */
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#other2 {
  grid-area: O2;

  /* internal to the content: */
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#editor-cell {
  grid-area: E;
  align-self: stretch;
}

#editor-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

#editor-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#editor {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.js"></script>
<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="other1">Other</div>
  <div id="other2">Content</div>
  <div id="editor-cell">
    <div id="editor-wrapper">
      <div id="editor-container">
        <div id="editor"><p>Sample</p><p>Line 2</p><p>Line 3</p><p>Line 4</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question thought I would answer anyway. You can manipulate the quill editor using the selector.  OF cours you can add an overriding CSS (use !important)

In JavaScript:

```
$(".ql-editor").css("height", 300)})
```

In CSS:

```
.ql-editor{
    height: 300px!important;
 }
```

Comment: The second paragraph of my question says "I do not want to hard-code any heights". The height of the other contents can vary, and the quill-editor should adapt. So this solution does not work.

Comment: Yes there are two examples in my reply. The first one is JavaScript so you can dynamically control height of quill on events. There is no way to do auto height using CSS.